# How can I use pkcs11 in mac os(10.9) native programs?

Tags: osx-mavericks, pki, pkcs#11

First, I can't communicate in english very well.

I will develop PKI.

I can control token in firefox, thunderbird but can't control mac native program(ex. safari, mail).

How can I control the token in os x 10.9(mavericks) native program (ex. safari, mail) ?

I heard use tokend but, also heard now tokend is deprecated.

Is that right?

and, I saw macosforge.org. but I didn't know.

frankly speaking, I'm a Windows developer. so, I don't know much about mac development environments.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

TokenD is technically deprecated (as is the entire CDSA subsystem it sits upon) since at OSX 10.7.

It sounds like you want a PKCS#11 module to work with native components, you may want to take a look at Gemalto's PKCS#11 -> TokenD bridge: https://smartcardservices.macosforge.org/trac/browser/trunk/Tokend/PKCS11

Note that TokenD -> PKCS#11 usage is tricky in that updates to the contents of the PKCS#11 device may or may not show up until you remove/insert the token.

If you are unfamiliar with Mac OSX build environments, you will likely want to hire/contract out with someone familiar with legacy Mac OSX security (I say legacy since the "new" environment does not yet interact with external security devices).